# Is there any way to run this code without getting the use of unassigned local variable error in the second case of the switch?

Tags: c#

I tried to make a program in which the first option gets some input and the second one puts the output but I get an error which says that the 's' variable isn't assigned, is there anyway to do this without getting the error but getting the input every time i press 1?

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string nume, prenume, facultate;
            int opt, varsta;
            double medieGenerala;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Introduceti optiunea dumneavoastra:");
                Console.WriteLine("0. Iesire");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Introduceti un nou student in catalog");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Afisati studentii din catalog");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Cautati un student dupa nume");
                opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch(opt)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
{
                        Console.Write("Introduceti numele studentului:- ");
                        nume = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Introduceti prenumele studentului:- ");
                        prenume = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Introduceti varsta studentului:- ");
                        varsta = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Introduceti media generala a studentului:- ");
                        medieGenerala = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Introduceti facultatea la care este studentul:- ");
                        facultate = Console.ReadLine();
                        Student[] s = new Student[]
                        {
                            new Student(nume,prenume,varsta,medieGenerala,facultate)
                        };
                        break;
}
                    case 2:
                        foreach(Student st in s)
                       {

                       }
                        break;
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `case 1` and `case 2` have different scope. Although you define `s` in `case 1` it is not visible in `case 2`.

Comment: You could move `Student[] s` out of the loop and initialize it with an empty array.

Comment: You might assume that the user's input will always cause `case 2:` to be executed after `case 1:`, but the compiler can't make that assumption. Consider the state of `s` if the user enters `2` before they enter `1` and what you might do to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instead of declaring your `Student` array in the `switch` statement, you declare it outside of the statement. Then you can work with it in any `case` section.

Your code could be updated to something like:

```
            // create list prior to the switch statement
            List<Student> s = new List<Student>();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Introduceti optiunea dumneavoastra:");
                Console.WriteLine("0. Iesire");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Introduceti un nou student in catalog");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Afisati studentii din catalog");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Cautati un student dupa nume");
                opt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch(opt)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        Console.Write("Introduceti numele studentului:- ");
                        nume = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Introduceti prenumele studentului:- ");
                        prenume = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("Introduceti varsta studentului:- ");
                        varsta = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Introduceti media generala a studentului:- ");
                        medieGenerala = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("Introduceti facultatea la care este studentul:- ");
                        facultate = Console.ReadLine();

                        // change array declaration to just add a new student to list here
                        s.Add(new Student(nume,prenume,varsta,medieGenerala,facultate));
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2:
                    {
                        foreach(Student st in s)
                       {
                          // now s is usable in here
                       }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a code block (`{`/`}`) surrounding the `case 1` code which creates a new declaration space. Variables declared within the code block cannot be referenced outside the block, e.g. in the `case 2` code.

It's not clear why the block is created and all the stranger that the braces are not indented. Otherwise all of the variables would be available within the scope of the `switch` statement.